# How to initialize several elements per iteration with Table?

Tags: list-manipulation, vector

I would like to initialize this kind of vector : `{0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1}` with `Table`.
I tried `Table[{x, y, 1}, {y, 0, 1, 1}, {x, 0, 1, 1}]` but it outputs `{{0,0,1},{1,0,1},{0,1,1},{1,1,1}}`.
What is the right method to correctly initialize my vector without creating sub-lists ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Table[{x, y, 1}, {y, 0, 1, 1}, {x, 0, 1, 1}] // Flatten
```

gives

```
{0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider also:

```
Flatten @ Array[{#2, #, 1} &, {2, 2}, 0]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

This is faster than `Table`, if applicable:

```
n = 2200;

Table[{x, y, 1}, {y, 0, n}, {x, 0, n}] // Flatten // Length // Timing
Array[{#2, #, 1} &, {n, n} + 1, 0]     // Flatten // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.435209, 14533203}
>
> {0.280802, 14533203}
> ```